# html data event.target data is undefined in lightning aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I have the following html and javascript code. In the code below, the **data-list-view-name** at the li html attribute is specified and the onclick handleSelectListView. However, the javascript **let selectedListViewName = event.target.dataset.listViewName** is returning undefined. Any advice on what I am doing incorrectly here?

```
 <div aura:id="listview-switcher-cmp" class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click">
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-small" aria-haspopup="true" title="Select Item" onclick="{! c.toggleListViewDropdown }" >
    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down" size="x-small" class="list-view-menu"/>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select Item</span>
</button>

<div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid slds-dropdown_right" role="listbox">
    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
    <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
        <div id="option0" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small" role="presentation">
        <div class="slds-text-title_caps slds-listbox__option-header">List Views</div>
        </div>
    </li>   

      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-list-view-name="Selection 1" onclick="{! c.handleSelectListView }">

    <div id="option1" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-check" >
            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:check" size="xx-small" class="list-view-item-selected" />
        </span>
        </span>
        <span class="slds-media__body slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
        <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">Selection 1</span>

        </span>

    </div>

      </li>
      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" data-list-view-name="Selection 2" onclick="{! c.handleSelectListView }">
    <div id="option2" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option">
        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small" >
            <!--NOT SELECTED-->
        </span>
        <span class="slds-media__body slds-p-top_xx-small slds-p-bottom_xx-small" >
        <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity" >Selection 2</span>
        </span>
    </div>
      </li>                                              
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

And in the following javascript code, the data-list-view-name is not returning the value. It is getting undefined. A

```
handleSelectListView: function(component,event,helper){

        let listViewCmp = component.find('listview-switcher-cmp');
        let selectedListViewName = event.target.dataset.listViewName;

        if($A.util.hasClass(listViewCmp,'slds-is-open')) {
            $A.util.removeClass(listViewCmp, 'slds-is-open');
        }

        alert(selectedListViewName);
 

    }
```

This is what it would look like...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on "Selection 1" (or "Selection 2") you're clicking on `<span>` element, not on `<li>`, so `event.target` refers to the `<span>` element, which has no data attribute, that's why  `dataset.listViewName` is undefined.
You should use `event.currentTarget.dataset.listViewName`:

- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, `<li>` in your case
- `event.target` identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant, `<span>`  in your case.

Comment: This resolves my issue! THANK YOU so much!